# Slow Performance with Django and Remote PostgreSQL on Docker - Local vs. Production Environment

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, deployment, vps

I'm encountering a significant performance issue with my Django application when using a remotely hosted PostgreSQL database in a production environment. My setup involves a Django application running locally and connecting to a PostgreSQL database hosted on a server.

**Local Environment:**

Both Django and PostgreSQL are running locally.
Operations, such as importing 1000 rows from an Excel file, are almost instantaneous.

**Production Environment:**

Django is running locally, but PostgreSQL is hosted on a server with the following specs: 4 vCPU cores, 16GB RAM.
The same operation takes about 3 minutes.

Docker Compose for Production (docker-compose.prod.yml):

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: postgis/postgis:16-3.4
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql.conf"]
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
      - ./pg_hba.conf:/etc/pg_hba.conf
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - db_network
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  # Other services like backup, pgadmin, etc.

networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /var/database/postgres_data
      o: bind
```

**Observations:**

The server doesn't seem to be under heavy load (low CPU and sufficient RAM).
Network ping tests to the server show latency varying from 35ms to over 100ms.
I'm trying to understand why there's such a significant difference in performance between the local and production setups. The server is powerful, and network latency, although present, doesn't seem high enough to cause such a drastic slowdown.

**Questions:**

Could the Docker volume configuration (type: none and device: /var/database/postgres_data) be contributing significantly to this slowdown?
Are there any specific Docker or PostgreSQL configurations I should look into to optimize performance in this scenario?
Any other suggestions for troubleshooting or resolving this performance issue?
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no magic shortcut for this. Turn on query logging in PostgreSQL and turn on logging at the django end. Compare timestamps. That will tell you where the issue is.

Comment: Bind mounts can be substantially slower on systems using Docker Desktop.  I expect you aren't in a production environment, but switching to a standard named volume (deleting all of the options under the `volumes: { postgres_data: }` declaration) is potentially faster, at the cost of being harder to manage in some ways.  If you're using tools like `pgbackup` and `pgrestore` to back up the data, you won't notice.

Comment: I have tried to remove all options but there is no improvements.